# How to use VB code to find multiple criteria match

Tags: vba, excel, search

I am looking to write a macro that finds the last match of based on criteria in both columns C and columns E and returns the row that match was found in.

I have a long sheet of data and I would like to pick a row, and search above that row for the most recent match of 2 criteria.  I am able to do this for 1 column but I'm not sure how to add the second.

Comment: VB.NET doesnt do macros, so you are off to a bad start with the wrong tag

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? Probably feasible with a formula.  Please specify what you want to do with that row once found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.  I've got the criteria hard coded but you could assign those from cells or user input or whatever.

```
Sub test()


Dim LowerBound As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Criteria1 As Variant
Dim Criteria2 As Variant

Criteria1 = "something"
Criteria2 = "somethingelse"

LowerBound = Selection.Row

If LowerBound > 1 Then
  For i = LowerBound - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = Criteria1 And Cells(i, 5).Value = Criteria2 Then
      MsgBox "i"
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End If


End Sub
```